# Moving Azure resources and update them with an ARM template

Tags: azure-resource-manager

Moving resources is easy, but will the ARM template, which uses ‘uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)’, still update the moved resources or create new resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will create new resources. From the [documentation on uniquestring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-functions-string#uniquestring) it creates a *deterministic* unique hash from the parameters. You're feeding the resourceGroup id to create the hash. If that resource group id changes, so will the hash.

If you're appending a value to create uniqueness - a simple way is to change the template to refer to a variable called suffix, and directly assign the previously created unique id to the suffic variable.

If you wanted to create a portable, reusable template that would allow you to move resources between groups, then you'll need a different value to seed your deterministic hash, and not something that's likely to change. I use subscription().id frequently.

Another thing to look at is the [template function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authoring-templates#functions) which allows you to define your own functions. You can encapsulate the unique naming logic in there also.

Probably not the answer you wanted to here though.